# Why is initial curve not assumed to be coincident with characteristics

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I was reading the method of characteristic for first order p.d.e's.
$a\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+b\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=c$.
Now it said to find out the solution we try to find out a specific curve along which the pde becomes an ode. This part I get, since the curve is where the first order derivatives get discontinuous. But why does it say that the initial data curve should not coincide with this chatacteristic. What will happen if the initial conditions are specified on the boundary. Can somebody give an example.?
Say i have the equation as $$yp+q=2$$ with $u$ known on the initial curve $y=0, 0\leq x\leq1$. So i get the characteristics and solution as
$y^2=2(x-x_R)$ and $u= 2y +u_R$

Comment: In your edited question, you have $p=u_x$ and $q=u_y$, right? There, the line $y=0$ is *not* a characteristic curve (the characteristics are parabolas, as you have computed), so the problem in question doesn't arise.

Comment: What if the initial curve was $y^2=2x$

Comment: Well, as I've said twice already (in my answer and in a comment there), such a problem would typically not have a solution! The only way it could have a solution is if the data given on the curve satisfies $u=2y+u_R$. But in that case, the given data would tell you *nothing* about what $u$ is supposed to do on the *other* characteristic curves, so the solution would be highly non-unique.

Comment: Don't thing that it is forbiden for the boundary condition to be defined on a characteristic curve. But in this case the consequence is unusual. See my answer.

Comment: Yes I think this assumption is needed when we try numerical schemes because then we want to be assured that the solution is unique.

Answer (score 1):

If you give data along a characteristic curve, the solution $u$ has two possibly conflicting jobs to do: (1) satisfy the ODE along the characteristic, and (2) satisfy the given condition along the characteristic.

As a simple example, try solving the PDE $u_x=0$ subject to the condition $u(x,0)=x$. Good luck! :-)

Comment: I get $u(x,y)=g(y)$ and by the initial condition i get $g(0)= x$ which is not consistent. But what do we say in a general case.

Comment: @Upstart: I don't understand what you mean. In the general case, you will typically get something inconsistent too.

Answer (score 1):

You ask to solve (for example) :
$$yp+q=y\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=2\tag 1$$
The Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs are :
$$\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{2}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{1}$ :
$$x-\frac12 y^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{2}$ :
$$u-2y=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u-2y=F\left(x-\frac12 y^2\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary condition).
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=2y+F\left(x-\frac12 y^2\right)} \tag 2$$
Then, all depends on the given boundary condition which can a continuous function or not, a picewise function or not.

Depending of the boundary condition the solution might exists or not or be not unique, might be continuous or not, piecewise or not.

In the question you wrote "with $u$ known on the initial curve $y=0$ , $0\leq x\leq 1."$ I suppose that you mean : $u(x,0)=f(x)$ with a given (known) function $f(x)$. If not let us know what you mean.

So with the condition : $u(x,0)=f(x)$ that we put into the general solution :
$$f(x)=u(x,0)=0+F(x-0)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=f(x)$$
Now the function $F$ is known since the function $f$ is given :
$$F(X)=f(X)\quad\text{any } X$$
We put it into the above general solution where $X=x-\frac12 y^2$
$$u(x,y)=2y+f\left(x-\frac12 y^2\right) \tag 3$$
The difference with equation $(2)$ is that $f$ is known instead of arbitrary $F$ in Eq.$(2)$.

Now we have to discuss about the "given" function $f$ in your question.

You didn't say what is $u(x,0)$ on $0\leq x \leq 1.$  So the boundary condition is hill posed and one cannot say if a solution exists or not or if they are many solutions.

You wrote : "So i get the characteristics and solution as $y^2=2(x−x_R)$ and $u=2y+u_R$ ".

What do you mean with $x_R$ and $u_R$ which appears like fly in the ointment ?

SEVERAL DIFFERENT EXAMPLES OF BOUNDARY CONDITION.

First example :

With the condition $u(x,0)=x^2$. The boundary $y=0$ is not a characteristic curve.
$$u(x,0)=x^2=0+F(x)\quad\implies\quad F(x)=x^2$$
$$u(x,y)=2y+\left(x-\frac12 y^2\right)^2$$

Second example :

With condition $u(x,y)=0$ on $y^2=2x$. The boundary is on a characteristic curve.
$$u(x,y)=0=2y+F(0) \quad\implies\quad y=\text{constant, which is not true any }y.$$
$$\text{There exists no solution for }u(x,y).$$

Third example :

With condition $u(x,y)=2y$ on $x-\frac12 y^2=1$. The boundary is on a characteristic curve.

$$u(x,y)=2y=2y+F(1)\quad\implies\quad F(1)=0$$
There exist an infinity of functions which are nul at argument=$1$. Thus :
$$\text{They are an infinity of solutions for }u(x,y)\: :$$

$F(X)=X-1 \quad\to\quad u(x,y)=2y+\left(x-\frac12 y^2\right)-1$

$F(X)=X^4-1 \quad\to\quad u(x,y)=2y+\left(x-\frac12 y^2\right)^4-1$

$F(X)=\sin(X-1) \quad\to\quad u(x,y)=2y+\sin\left(x-\frac12 y^2-1\right)$

Etc.